# iptables FORWARD chain rule clarification

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, iptables

I currently trying to learn iptables, and was wondering if someone could clarify what exactly is happening here. The rules in question are from the FORWARD chain (see below) on my router connected to the modem and all devices connect via the router. My understanding is that the FORWARD chain is for passing traffic on your LAN for the most part, but this section from my 'iptables-save' seems to have an excessive amount of rules that seem to leave this section completely open anyway. I have posted my ifconfig, and the FORWARD chain for iptables. The FORWARD chain default rule is DROP.

Thanks!

FORWARD CHAIN

> -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>
> -A FORWARD -i ! br0 -o eth0 -j DROP
>
> -A FORWARD -i eth0 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
>
> -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A FORWARD -j NSFW
>
> -A FORWARD -o eth0 -j triggers
>
> -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j TRIGGER --trigger-proto --trigger-match 0-0 --trigger-relate 0-0
>
> -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
>
> -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT

ifconfig

> br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:60:6E:BD:6C:A0
>            inet addr:192.168.XXX.2  Bcast:192.168.XXX.255  >Mask:255.255.255.0
>            UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>            RX packets:2806607 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>            TX packets:2104335 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>            collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>            RX bytes:2131028144 (1.9 GiB)  TX bytes:2109076563 (1.9 GiB)
>
> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:60:6E:BD:6C:A0
>            inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Bcast:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  >Mask:255.255.248.0
>            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>            RX packets:21648433 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>            TX packets:16948289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>            RX bytes:3940957536 (3.6 GiB)  TX bytes:2242887246 (2.0 GiB)
>            Interrupt:4 Base address:0x2000
>
> ..... CROPPED